# Password Show Hide when click on eye icon on login page

Tags: javascript

Hi I was trying to do password hide and show by clicking on eye icon in javascript. But when i search this concept, I can get the Jquery results only. I want to implement in Ionic Project . Can anyone please help on this ?

```
    <ion-input type="password" positionV="bottom" arrow click name="password"
          [(ngModel)]="password" required>
          <ion-icon name="eye-outline" id="togglePassword"></ion-icon>
        </ion-input>
```

I dont know how to do in javascript

Comment: Where is your code?????

Comment: It's simple as changing the input element type

Answer (score 1):

Below is code in core javascript

```js
 function showPassword() {
      document.getElementById('pass-field').type = 'text';
    }
    
    function hidePassword() {
      document.getElementById('pass-field').type = 'password';
    }
```

```html
  
  <div class="password-field">
    <input id="pass-field" type="password">
    <a onmousedown="showPassword()" onmouseup="hidePassword()" id="eye-btn" href="#">eye</a>
  </div>
```

you just have to add events onmousedown and onmouseup and change input element type to text.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using Ionic the best way is to create a directive as explained in link shared below follow the same steps.

https://codeburst.io/a-simple-show-and-hide-password-directive-with-angular-fae7a6bd136